# Accessing a JNDI DataSource without the java:comp/env prefix

Tags: java, websphere, jndi

I've noticed that both ways of looking up a `DataSource` using JNDI work:

1. jdbc/DataSource
2. java:comp/env/jdbc/DataSource

With the added bonus that the first one doesn't seem to anger Websphere when used from an unmanaged thread ( started by Quartz ).

Are there any pitfalls from accessing JNDI objects without the prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be OK, since `java:comp/env` is the global JNDI namespace. 
It may depend on the application server where such configurations also appear in the JNDI tree.

[Locate your JDBC DataSource in WebSphere Application Server using JNDI](http://zatz.com/webspherepower/article/locate-your-jdbc-datasource-in-websphere-application-server-using-jndi/)

Comment: Thanks. I think that the link is broken.

Comment: java:comp/env doesn't work if you are coming from a (non-container) application (at least with WebSphere). So then you have to stick to the first name when looking up the resource.

Comment: Same thing with WebLogic, where it affects lookup from any thread that is not directly managed by the container.  For example, from a WLS thread you can use "java:comp/env/jmx/runtime" but from a non-WLS thread you must lookup "java:comp/jmx/runtime".